# iOS Map box installation using .netrc file

Tags: ios, mapbox, access-token, mapbox-ios

Even I am facing the same issue, I followed steps from below URL, https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/overview/ for setting up a secret and public tokens, but still getting the same issue

[!] Error installing Mapbox-iOS-SDK [!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/mk/dxhjgx491qs_r3dq0hbt7k5mk9qp25/T/d20200914-2904-qefyh6/file.zip https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/mobile-maps/releases/ios/packages/6.1.0/mapbox-ios-sdk-dynamic.zip --create-dirs --netrc-optional --retry 2

% Total % Received % Xferd Average Speed Time Time Time Current Dload Upload Total Spent Left Speed 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 --:--:-- 0:00:06 --:--:-- 0 curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 401 Unauthorized

Answer (score 3):

Issue resolved, we need to add .netrc in the home directory of your Mac, I was trying to add that file in the project home directory.

All the required pods are installed without any error.

Comment: hi @afsara what you write in .netrc file? I'm not able to install map box, created .netrc.